# I dont know where the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error emerges from my java code

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem to be solved is as follows:

[image: The question]

My code is as follows:

```java
package problem2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Chipychipy {
    int numberColumns;
    int[][] Boarded = new int[2][numberColumns];

    void getValues() {
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of Columns: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        numberColumns = scan.nextInt();
        for (int x = 0; x < numberColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the value of Column " + (x + 1) + " and Row number " + (y + 1));
                int Board_input = scan.nextInt();
                Boarded[y][x] = Board_input;
            }
        }
    }

    void printValues() {
        System.out.println("\n______________\n");
        System.out.println("The array entered is: ");
        for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < numberColumns; f++) {
                System.out.print(Boarded[d][f] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    int chips(int i) {
        int x, y, z;
        if (i > numberColumns) {
            // termination condition
            return 0;
        } else {
            x = Boarded[0][(i - 1)] + chips((i + 1));
            y = Boarded[0][(i - 1)] + chips((i + 2));
            z = Boarded[0][(i - 1)] + chips((i + 3));
            if (Boarded[1][(i - 1)] == 1) {
                return x;
            } else if (Boarded[1][(i - 1)] == 2) {
                return Math.min(x, y);
            } else {
                return Math.min(x, Math.min(y, z));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Cheaperer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //created Scanner object
            int number, result;
            //int [] T = new int[6];
            System.out.println("App starting point:");
            //System.out.println("Please enter the starting point:");
            //number= scan.nextInt();
            Random rand = new Random();
            int upperbound = 5;
            number = 1 + rand.nextInt(upperbound);
            Chipychipy cheapobj = new Chipychipy();
            cheapobj.getValues();
            cheapobj.printValues();
            result = cheapobj.chips(number);
            System.out.println("Starting=" + number + " cheap = " + result);

        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to allow me to enter values of a multidimensional array and calculate the cheapest cost of moving through them

```sh
App starting point:
Enter the Number of Columns: 
3
Enter the value of Column 1 and Row number 1
100
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at problem2.Chipychipy.getValues(Cheaperer.java:17)
    at problem2.Chipychipy$Cheaperer.main(Cheaperer.java:64)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve this? I would like it to display the cheapest cost and also make a table to store the values in case of a re-run, we just fetch from the table

Comment: What value do you expect `numberColumns` to have here: `int[][] Boarded = new int[2][numberColumns];`? You're calling `numberColumns = scan.nextInt();` in `getValues()` but think about when `Boarded` (btw, read up on the Java code conventions to make your life easier) is initialized. That happens when the `Chipychipy` instance is created, i.e. _before_ `getValues()` can even be called.

Comment: It should accept one to specify the number of columns in the game, e.g. 20, then to enter the values in the cost and number of columns it can jump before calculating the cheapest cost

Comment: You need to (re)initialize the array after reading the size then.